# Searching a list of words using Boolean operators

Tags: lists, conditionals, expl3

In the project I'm currently working on, the user can define, within an environment defined by the project, a list of tags, stored internally in a macro (for example, `\tags`). Each item in this list consists of one or more words, and superfluous spaces and numbers (for example, `\tags` could be `{foo, bar, baz qux , quux2, Corge Grault}`).

I'd like to know how to define a `\mytest` command that would test whether or not one or more words supplied by the user belong to the `\tags` list and execute a code according to the test result. The user should be able to use Boolean operators (and, or, not), any superfluous spaces should be eliminated, and there could be an option to determine whether or not the search should take into account word case.

For example, if `\tags={foo, bar, baz qux , quux2, Corge Grault}`
and if `\userinput=(foo && BAR ) || garply` then `\mytest{\userinput}{\tags}{true}{false}` would return `true` while `\mytest[1]{\userinput}{\tags}{true}{false}`
would return `false`, assuming that the optional parameter `[1]` provided means that the search is case-sensitive.

I have a feeling that LaTeX3 could prove particularly useful in solving this problem, but unfortunately I'm not competent enough to achieve the desired result.

Any help would be most welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `\mytest` has an optional `*` for case sensitivity.

It uses `\str_map_inline:nn` to loop over the second argument.

On each item in this loop, `\tl_set_rescan:Nnn` is performed. Then it is verified if this element is `|`, `&`, `(` or `)`.

The function `\__searching_if_in:` starts with `\tl_trim_spaces:N`. It constructs `\l__searching_boolean_expression_tl`. At the end, this is interpreted by `\bool_if:nTF`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l__searching_tags_clist
\tl_new:N \l__searching_accumulate_text_tl
\tl_new:N \l__searching_boolean_expression_tl
\tl_new:N \l__searching_text_item_tl
\cs_new:Npn \__searching_if_in:
  {
    \tl_trim_spaces:N \l__searching_accumulate_text_tl
    \tl_if_empty:NF \l__searching_accumulate_text_tl
      {
        \clist_if_in:NVTF \l__searching_tags_clist \l__searching_accumulate_text_tl
          { \tl_put_right:Nn \l__searching_boolean_expression_tl { \c_true_bool } }
          { \tl_put_right:Nn \l__searching_boolean_expression_tl { \c_false_bool } }
      }
    \tl_clear:N \l__searching_accumulate_text_tl
  }
\NewDocumentCommand { \mytest } { s m m m m }
  {
    \clist_set:NV \l__searching_tags_clist #3
    \tl_clear:N \l__searching_accumulate_text_tl
    \tl_clear:N \l__searching_boolean_expression_tl
    \str_map_inline:nn {#2}
      {
        \tl_set_rescan:Nnn \l__searching_text_item_tl {} {##1}
        \tl_if_in:nVTF { | & ( ) } \l__searching_text_item_tl
          {
            \__searching_if_in:
            \tl_put_right:NV \l__searching_boolean_expression_tl \l__searching_text_item_tl
          }
          {
            \IfBooleanTF {#1}
              { \tl_put_right:NV \l__searching_accumulate_text_tl \l__searching_text_item_tl }
              { \tl_put_right:Ne \l__searching_accumulate_text_tl { \text_lowercase:n { \l__searching_text_item_tl } } }
          }
      }
    \__searching_if_in:
    \bool_if:nTF { \l__searching_boolean_expression_tl } {#4} {#5}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newcommand{\tags}{foo , bar , baz qux , quux2 , Corge Grault}
\begin{document}
\mytest{(foo && BAR ) || garply}{\tags}{true}{false}
\mytest*{(foo && BAR ) || garply}{\tags}{true}{false}
\mytest{ bAr & & foO }{\tags}{true}{false}
\mytest{   baz qux   }{\tags}{true}{false}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It really makes me want to dive into the expl3 documentation so that I can understand your code and in turn manage to produce my own code. However, your code doesn't seem to take the negation operator ( ! ) into account. Would this be difficult to implement?

Comment: @user30654 The negation can be added by adding `!` to the list with `\tl_if_in:nVTF { | & ( ) ! }`.

Comment: that's what i did but, in that case, `\mytest{!waldo}{\tags}{true}{false}` returns `false` instead of `true` and `\mytest{!(waldo||foo)}{\tags}{true}{false}` leads to an error (_Missing number, treated as zero_).

Comment: @user30654 In that case it was probably forgotten to add `!` to the list. If `!` is added with `\tl_if_in:nVTF { | & ( ) ! }` then `\mytest{!waldo}{\tags}{true}{false}` gives true and `\mytest{!(waldo||foo)}{\tags}{true}{false}` gives false without error. Maybe the version of `expl3` is too old. Then an option is to update. Another option is to place `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_in:nnTF { nVTF } \cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_put_right:Nn { Ne }` after `\ExplSyntaxOn`.

Comment: Thanks for your patience! I've found the culprit: it's because I have `\usepackage[french]{babel}` in my header and, I guess, the problem then comes from the fact that the `!` character is made active. Any idea of a possible workaround?

Comment: After delving into the documentation, I have the impression that by replacing `\tl_set_rescan:Nnn \l__searching_text_item_tl {} {##1}` with `\tl_set_rescan:Nnn \l__searching_text_item_tl { \char_set_catcode_other:N ! } {##1}` works (with babel/french) and gives the desired result. But I'm not sure it's the right way to do it...

Comment: @user30654 If `\usepackage[french]{babel}` is used then a solution is to place \begingroup\catcode```!=12 right after the first brace of the body of the command `\mytest` (thus right before `\clist_set:NV`) and `\endgroup` right before the closing brace of the body (thus right after `{#5}`). Your solution to place `\char_set_catcode_other:N !` inside `\tl_set_rescan:Nnn` amounts to the same.

Comment: In the previous comment about `\catcode` there should only be 1 backtick instead of 3 but the markdown editor uses this symbol for formatting.

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much for your help!